# Is there a standard function in Clojure that takes an argument, ignores it and returns a constant?

Tags: clojure

Is there a standard function in Clojure that does:

```
(defn const [x] (fn [_] x))
```

?

Comment: `(constantly x)` http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/constantly

Comment: @ymonad Your comment should be answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `constantly` does what you want: http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/constantly